# How to add Retargeting tag into each page?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using drupal - 7.

I wanted to embed `<script>` tags for Retargeting tag into each page of the Website, between the `<body> </body>` tags.

I am new to Drupal. I am trying to create custom block module for this.

I have created custom module to place  tags into custom block. I am not sure what I have done is right or wrong. Can any one help me with this?

**I just wanted to add script like this into each page for Retargeting tags for campaigns**

```
<script async src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=0&segment=Segment+Name&campaign_id=0"></script>
```

I have added script tag into my js file which I have called from .info file.
In my .info file I called;

```
scripts[] = MyCustomBlock.js
```

This is the code for my custom block module.

```
/**  * Implements hook_help().  *  * Displays help and module
information.  *  * @param path   *   Which path of the site we're
using to display help  * @param arg   *   Array that holds the current
path as returned from arg() function  */    

function MyCustomBlock_help($path, $arg) {   
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#MyCustomBlock":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays links to nodes created on this date") . '</p>';
      break;   
  } 
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/
/**  * Declaring the block  */
function MyCustomBlock_block_info() {
  $blocks['MyCustomBlock'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('MyCustomBlock'),
    // Default setting.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,   
  );   
  return $blocks; 
} 

/**  * Preparing for a module configuration form  * Implements
hook_menu().  */

function MyCustomBlock_menu() {   
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/MyCustomBlock'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyCustomBlock',
    'description' => 'Configuration for MyCustomBlock module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MyCustomBlock_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,   
  );

  return $items; 
}


/*  * Adding JavaScript from within a module  */

function MyCustomBlock_add_js($data = NULL, $options = NULL) {   
    $javascript = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());   
    $jquery_added = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__ . ':jquery_added', FALSE);
}
```

I can see my block module in the `/admin/modules` section and I can enable my custom block module. But, I am not sure how to add that script into my module.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: unless you are running multiple themes, why not just add it to a custom html.tpl.php in the theme directory - you decide exactly what you want, and where you want it, without having to add a new module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) doesn't support the async property (there is a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1664602) however) but the simplest solution would be to just just add that line to your `html.tpl.php` as Geoff suggested.

Comment: But, wouldn't it break, If I add it in html.tpl.php file?
Or should I create just copy of html.tpl.php file? - I am newbie so apologize for some silly questions.

Comment: I am getting this error with my custom module:
Notice: Undefined index: mycampaign_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 806 of ../includes/form.inc).

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mycampaign_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 841 of ../includes/form.inc).

I have just changed the name of module from 'MyCustomBlock' to 'mycampaign' because of camel-case in the module name.

Comment: Copy html.tpl.php into your own theme and edit it there. Just one question per thread please.